# Why is my site different depending on the URL used to access it?

Tags: url, caching, web

I have recently developed a website for a client, and I've made changes to fix some of the issues they had with it, and since, I've uploaded a new version to my new server.

Somehow though, this new version of the site can only be accessed through the non-www url. For example, if you go to [non-www version](http://etherealmassagetherapy.com), the non-working version, you'll notice that it is different from [www version](http://www.etherealmassagetherapy.com), the working version.

Maybe it is my computer, but I've tried clearing my cache and such. Is there maybe a way to reset the cached version on the server somehow? I don't think I even set it to cache though.

Any ideas on why these two different URLs result in two different site?

Comment: What is running on the server?  How is it configured?  Do you have multiple IP's?

Comment: @chicks I don't know super specifics about any back end things, only broad strokes. I know it's an Linux apache server running PHP, not sure what version. There are a couple files in the root directory of this site named like 400 and 500 (I forget the file extension, but I can check). I have an htaccess configured, but I don't fully understand it. It's pieces picked from the internet. About the IPs, I have no idea.

Comment: I get the same HTML for both pages. (I don’t run JavaScript though, so if the changes only come from JS, that’s where the issue probably is then.)